# Breaking up paragraphs into String tokens

Tags: java, algorithm, substring

I am able to break up paragraphs of text into substrings based upon nth given character limit. The conflict I have is that my algorithm is doing exactly this, and is breaking up words. This is where I am stuck. If the character limit occurs in the middle of a word, how can I back track to a space so that all my substrings have entire words?

This is the algorithm I am using

```
int arrayLength = 0;
arrayLength = (int) Math.ceil(((mText.length() / (double) charLimit)));

String[] result = new String[arrayLength];
int j = 0;
int lastIndex = result.length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
    result[i] = mText.substring(j, j + charLimit);
    j += charLimit;
}

result[lastIndex] = mText.substring(j);
```

I am setting the charLimit variable with any nth, integer value. And mText is string with a paragraph of text. Any suggestions on how I can improve this? Thank you in advance.

I am receiving good responses, just so you know what I did to figure out of I landed on a space or not, I used this while loop. I just do not know how to correct from this point.

```
while (!strTemp.substring(strTemp.length() - 1).equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
    // somehow refine string before added to array
}
```

Comment: You may check mText length is greater or equal to difference between charlimit and length of current total words.

Comment: Check for each character if it is a white space and every time that it is, update a variable holding the index of the white space. Once you get to the last iteration, if the next character is not a white space you know you are in the middle of a word. In that case, you can use the last white space index to know where you needed to stop.

Comment: @Jurgen, this is sort of what I was thinking also. However, this is the part I need the help with. Let me show you what I attempted, but its not working.

Comment: Could you use StringBuilder and append each iteration of white space so you would append each word, then set your char limit, and use modulus to cycle through in a for each loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly what you wanted but an answer to my interpretation:

You could find the last space before your character limit with [lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int,%20int)) and then check if you are close enough to your limit (for text without whitespace) i.e.:

```
int arrayLength = 0;
arrayLength = (int) Math.ceil(((mText.length() / (double) charLimit)));

String[] result = new String[arrayLength];
int j = 0;
int tolerance = 10;
int splitpoint;
int lastIndex = result.length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
    splitpoint = mText.lastIndexOf(' ' ,j+charLimit);
    splitpoint = splitpoint > j+charLimit-tolerance ? splitpoint:j+charLimit;
    result[i] = mText.substring(j, splitpoint).trim();
    j = splitpoint;
}

result[lastIndex] = mText.substring(j).trim();
```

this will search for the last space before `charLimit` (example value) and either split the string there if it is less then `tolerance` away or split at `charLimit` if it isn't.

Only problem with this solution is that the last Stringtoken can be longer than `charLimit` so you might need to adjust `arrayLength` and loop `while (mText - j > charLimit)`

---

Edit

running sample code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String mText =  "I am able to break up paragraphs of text into substrings based upon nth given character limit. The conflict I have is that my algorithm is doing exactly this, and is breaking up words. This is where I am stuck. If the character limit occurs in the middle of a word, how can I back track to a space so that all my substrings have entire words?";

    int charLimit = 40;
    int arrayLength = 0;
    arrayLength = (int) Math.ceil(((mText.length() / (double) charLimit)));

    String[] result = new String[arrayLength];
    int j = 0;
    int tolerance = 10;
    int splitpoint;
    int lastIndex = result.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
        splitpoint = mText.lastIndexOf(' ' ,j+charLimit);
        splitpoint = splitpoint > j+charLimit-tolerance ? splitpoint:j+charLimit;
        result[i] = mText.substring(j, splitpoint);
        j = splitpoint;
    }

    result[lastIndex] = mText.substring(j);

    for (int i = 0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I am able to break up paragraphs of text
 into substrings based upon nth given
 character limit. The conflict I have is
 that my algorithm is doing exactly
 this, and is breaking up words. This is
 where I am stuck. If the character
 limit occurs in the middle of a word,
 how can I back track to a space so that
 all my substrings have entire words?
```

**Additional Edit:** added trim() as per suggestion by curiosu. It removes whitespace surroundig the string tokens.

Comment: thank you for your answer, however, this does not work. In fact, words are missing now. And still the words are getting cut off.

Comment: Words at the end (last string) or from the middle? And how long are the words that are get cut off?

Comment: Improvement: add trim() for this solution:
-result[i] = mText.substring(j, splitpoint).trim();
-result[lastIndex] = mText.substring(j).trim();

Comment: Let me try this. Looks promising.

Comment: @curiosu added your suggestion

Comment: Success! This works really good Trudbert. Thank you everyone. +1 for everyone!

Comment: Another improvement:
- don't use that line (used in the question):
arrayLength = (int) Math.ceil(((mText.length() / (double) charLimit)));
because an example having String mText =  "abcdef abcdef abcdef"; and charLimit = 10 will not work. ( 20/10=2 != 3 )